# Angular animate ng-repeat slides

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I have recently been learning JavaScript and Angular around the same time and my knowledge in both is limited. I am building a music archive app in order to learn both these technologies better and have been attempting to animate a slider built with ng-repeat, at the moment, the slider animates into position when the page loads, but the button to load the next 'group' doesn't run the animation.

I have written my animation with Greensock and structured it like in the Angular API documentation. If anyone knows why my animation isn't running on every click of the button I am very grateful.

**Associated HTML..**

```
<div id="content-cent">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row animation" ng-repeat="group in trackDataGroup" ng-hide="!isCurrentSlideIndex($index)">
            <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="track in group">
                <div class="img-cont">
                    <img class="artwork" ng-src="{{track.art}}" />
                </div>
                <div class="txt-cont">
                    <h4>{{track.tit}}</h4>
                        <p>{{track.desc}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--end row-->
    </div>
            <img class="loadMore" src="public/img/dwn.png" ng-click="setCurrentSlideIndex()"/>
</div><!--end content-cent-->
```

**.animate module**

```
app.animation('.animation', function() {
    return {
        enter : function(element, done) {
            TweenMax.set(element, {x: "-50px", opacity: 0});
            TweenMax.to(element, 0.5, {x:"0px", opacity: 1, ease:Back.easeInOut, onComplete: done});
        },
        leave : function(element, done) {
            TweenMax.to(element, 0.5, {x:"50px", opacity: 0, ease:Back.easeInOut, onComplete: done});

        },
        move : function(element, done) {
            TweenMax.set(element, {x: "-50px", opacity: 0});
            TweenMax.to(element, 0.5, {x:"0px", opacity: 1, ease:Back.easeInOut, onComplete: done});
        }
    }
});
```

ng-app is declared in the html tag and ng-controller in the body tag.

The app is initialised with

```
var app = angular.module('musicApp', ['ngAnimate']);
```

and the majority of code is in app.controller.